# Evaluation of a recommendation system based on similarity criteria

Tags: recommendation-engine, evaluation, precision-recall

I have built a recommender system that recommends the first 10 items similar to an item, based on a set of a weighted metrics. Right now all one can do is select an item and the system shows the first 10 items similar to the selected item. I am confused on the evaluation techniques that can be used to evaluate such a system. Do Precision/recall estimates make sense in such cases where there are no users involved? Any pointers on evaluation techniques for such systems would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to evaluate precision and recall you need to have somehow the correct answers for some inputs. The correct answer in this case might mean the most similar item, or the exact ordered list of 10 similar items. Then you can compare the output of your algorithm with the correct answers. Given this information you also need a way to learn, i.e. to adjust your algorithm to get closer to the correct answer. This update part of your algorithm can be used also when you run the system with real users: if you show 10 related items to the real user and the user picks one of them, then you should update the weights so that the suggestion picked by the user has a higher rank next time. This may go even deeper if you profile the users and cluster them, so users from different categories will have to see different related items relative to a given item.